# Cassandra and Pycassa: Best way to determine if row with particular key exists

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

Using pycassa, what is the best way to determine if a record with particular key exists? Is this

```
try:
    cf.get(key, columns=[])
except pycassa.NotFoundException:
    # Not exists
else:
    # Exists
```

is a good solution? Will this use only key cache?

UPDATE: I just tried this query and it always raises `pycassa.NotFoundException` if `columns=[]` specified.

Answer (score 1):

To see if a specific row key exists in a cf you do:

```
>>> cf.get(key)
{'col_name': 'col_val', 'col_name2': 'col_val2'}
```

If that row key happens to be in the key cache then the value from cache will be used. 
You will need to look into the appropriate sstables to find the actual values that corresponds to this row key. This could require a (slow) disk seek/access unless you are lucky and hit the row cache or the (linux) page cache.

Comment: If nothing exists for the key, hopefully the Bloom filters will mean there is nothing looked up. If one or more Bloom filters gives a false positive, the key cache is consulted for the offset within the SSTable(s).

Comment: This will always fetch whole row data. Seems like there should be a bit more efficient way of doing this... At least in my situation I can fetch only one column.

Comment: Plus, when you have (many?) tombstones before the first "real" row, it is even slower...